# How exactly does a website connect to adobe analytics?

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

Recently I have a request to put adobe analytics in a website that I am working on. I already got the adobe analytics script for the website, here's the script :

```
<script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/launch-xxxxxx-development.min.js" async></script>
```

I repace the part after `launch` with `xxxxxx` just in case that part is confidential. I already add the script in the website in development environment, test it, and my co-worker that manage the adobe analytics dashboard claim that the data from my website already seen in the dashboard. My question is, how exactly does my website already sent the data to the dashboard? The problem is, the development environment is on-premise, which is not in the cloud or internet. Same with my production environment. I just want to make sure before I implement the script on production environment, which is on premise as well, do I have to connect to a certain server? Since my website is on-premise, I always have to make sure the connection if the website need to connect a certain website/API/server.

Answer (score 1):

The data collection JavaScript sends an HTTP GET request to Adobe's data collection servers for a 1x1 pixel image (often referred to as an image beacon) and transmits all the collected information to the Adobe server at that time. This is a standard "tracker" or data collection mechanism used across the internet. Your website doesn't have to be exposed to the internet, as long as the browser/javascript can make an HTTP GET request to the internet then it can send the image beacon.

There is tons of documentation available about it. Here is a starting point:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics/analyze/reports-analytics/reporting-interface/overview-data-collection.html?lang=en#reports-analytics

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I really appreciate it, does google analytics works like that as well? I already read the explanation of how google anayltics collects data in https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#gifRequestClassification , but I just want to make sure if google works like your explanation.

Comment: Yes, Google Analytics works the same way. The documentation you linked states that it also sends a single-pixel GIF request.